# Query on mixed input style SAS data.This code is not giving me proper output

Tags: sas

```
    DATA nationalparks;
    INPUT @1 ParkName $ 1-21  @23 State $ Year @40  Acreage COMMA9.;
    DATALINES;
    Yellowstone           ID/MT/WY 1872 4,065,493
    Everglades            FL       1934 1,398,800
    Yosemite              CA       1864 760,91
    Great Smoky Mountains NC/TN    1926 520,269
    ;
    RUN;
```

This SAS code is not showing proper result set.

Comment: Please provide the expected output and what the actual output is, and why it's wrong.

Comment: Your whole code including the lines of data appear to be indented a number of spaces.  The extra `RUN;` doesn't cause any problems (other than confusing users that are not familiar with using in-line data).

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks fine to me if the data really is in the columns your code is using.

Make sure you haven't indented the datalines. Also check that your editor hasn't replaced spaces with TAB characters. Make sure that STATE and YEAR always have a value and that the value does not include any spaces. You can use `.` to mark missing values, even for the character variable STATE.  You can read STATE and YEAR using columns instead and then blanks will be treated as missing. No need to use formatted input for the last variable, if you add the `:` modifier then SAS will use list mode and adjust the width used on the informat to match the width of the next value on the line.  But again if ACREAGE is missing then use `.` to mark that. Or add an `INFILE DATALINES TRUNCOVER;` statement before the INPUT statement.

```
DATA nationalparks;
  INPUT ParkName $ 1-21 State $ 23-30 Year 32-35 Acreage :COMMA.;
*---+----10---+----20---+----30---+----40---+----50;
DATALINES;
Yellowstone           ID/MT/WY 1872 4,065,493
Everglades            FL       1934 1,398,800
Yosemite              CA       1864 760,91
Great Smoky Mountains NC/TN    1926 520,269
;
```

Results:

```
Obs    ParkName                 State       Year    Acreage

 1     Yellowstone              ID/MT/WY    1872    4065493
 2     Everglades               FL          1934    1398800
 3     Yosemite                 CA          1864      76091
 4     Great Smoky Mountains    NC/TN       1926     520269
```